# How to force MS Publisher to use more memory?

Tags: windows-10, office365, microsoft-publisher

I'm using Microsoft Publisher for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2209) 64-bit edition for Enterprise, on a 16 core Xeon processor with 32 GB ram, and a NVIDEA Quadro RTX 4000 GPU which has 12 GB of dedicated ram.

I'm working on a Publisher document that is 3 feet x 9 feet in size, and it has large amount of text, and it has a file size of almost 30 MB.

The problem is that everything is painfully slow and it is taking upwards of 15 to 30 minutes, if not longer, to perform a simple task like scrolling, zooming, opening the master page view, or a refresh of the page.  It's using about 5% to 11% of the CPU and virtually no disk, network, or GPU, but Task Manager is reporting "Very High" power usage.

It is only using about 900 MB to 1.6 GB of ram, which varies when restarting the app, with the whole system only using 12.4 GB of ram, with about 19 GB available. Publisher is hitting a large number of page faults, it's hitting over 3 billion at times, and keeps climbing, and the IO isn't moving.  So to me, it looks like its just paging memory.

My question is, how can Publisher be forced to use more memory to hopefully reduce excessive paging?  I would think if it needs more ram, then it would use more, but with using less than 2 GB of ram I'm wondering if something is configured incorrectly.

Or is there something else that may be going on here that could be causing this issue?  I'm not sure what else to search for.

Update:

I didn't think there was a way to force win10 to use more memory, as a few commenters have stated, but the much-older versions of windows it was possible to set memory usage for the apps.  Just wasn't sure if there was some way to do that with win10, but guessing not, which is probably a very good idea.

To provide some background on what I'm trying to do with the publisher document, is that the document is a 3 foot x 9 foot banner.  Since the printers have a resolution of 1440x1440, I'm using repeating text to generate a background pattern.  From afar the pattern is soft and it's not obvious that it's text.  But when up close, then the text is readable and provides deeper context of what the banner's subject.

I was experimenting with using 20 point fonts for the background text, with a relative transparency of about 50% so it's muted and softer, but yet still readable up close. The best way to describe the text would be similar to a "word cloud", but it's liner text that's the same size, with about 10% being a different style (color and shadows) to stand out.  This text repeats to fully fill the master page, so that way it's in the background for the primary content to be super-imposed over the top of it all, without any wrapping around objects.  There were three primary styles.  1. Using bullets to act as separators between concepts.  2. Primary text. About 3 to 4 words. With shadows to help blur the text from afar (less sharp edges). 3. Special text, which is about 10%. Using gold font color, with a shadows to help the text to stand out from the white background.

It actually looks good, but in practice, it is a killer for Publisher.  I was able to copy and paste the text in to a word doc with 1/2 inch margins, and it resulted in 90+ pages.  So to put this in to perspective for Publisher, it's seeing this as a single paragraph, with hundreds of style changes every few words.  So for Publisher to try and "flow" such a huge paragraph is overwhelming and is locking up everything for 30+ minutes.

To help mitigate these short comings, I've made changes to my document to reduce the complexity of the text styles:

1. The bullets and primary text are the same style.
2. The primary text does not have shadows.
3. Font size is now 22 points (to reduce total text)
4. Added character spacing of 2.5 points (to reduce total text)

I have not yet finalized the text yet, but so far it's performing almost normally with just 75% of the master page filled with the text.  There is a little lag, but it's less than 1 second so it's tolerable.

Comment: “ My question is, how can Publisher be forced to use more memory to hopefully reduce excessive paging?” - You can’t

Comment: You can't force publishers to use more memory.

Comment: That's what I was fearing.  Thanks for the sanity check.
I'm assuming that it's having challenges with rendering large amounts of text, but totally surprised the performance is so horrible.  I just wonder why its having such problems, as if Publisher was never intended to deal with large text bodies with frequent style changes.  As if it goes in to a death spiral when trying to calculate the flow of the text for huge bodies.